# Mask in UITableViewCell subclass not properly rendering on first load

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to create a UITableViewCell subclass containing two rounded views, one on top and one on bottom, that together end up as a rounded rectangular view inside the cell, with indented space on all 4 sides (set by auto layout constrains in the storyboard for the prototype cell).  These cells are part of a tableview that is loaded into a UIContainerView which has its contents swapped out based on the selection of a selection control.

Here is what I want the cell to look like (blacked out):

[image: Properly Rendered]

Here is what it looks like briefly, when first loading:

[image: Briefly looks like this (insets appear not to render at first)]

Here is what it looks like after it first loads:

[image: Insets now working, but the mask on the top and bottom right appear not to render]

When I switch to a different tab, then come back, it renders the cell correctly.

I use this method in the parent view controller (adapted from [this](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/13/switching-child-view-controllers-ios-auto-layout/))

```
func cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: UIViewController, toViewController newViewController: UIViewController) {
    oldViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    self.addChildViewController(newViewController)
    self.addSubView(newViewController.view, toView:self.containerView!)
    newViewController.view.alpha = 0
    newViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        newViewController.view.alpha = 1
        oldViewController.view.alpha = 0
        },
        completion: { finished in
            oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            newViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    })
}
```

The parent view controller's viewDidLoad method is called like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

... // grab data in a background network call, populating the array of model objects
    self.currentSelectedViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addChildViewController(self.currentSelectedViewController!)
    self.addSubView(self.currentSelectedViewController!.view, toView: self.containerView)
    self.refreshContainerView()
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

refreshContainerView looks like this:

```
func refreshContainerView() {

    let currentVC = self.currentSelectedViewController as! MyTableViewController
        currentVC.modelObjectList = self.modelObjectList
        self.label.hidden = true
        self.button.hidden = true
        currentVC.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is my cell's layout subviews method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.reminderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    if let aModel = self.model {
        self.configureWithModel(aModel)
    } 

    self.setMaskToView(self.topView, corners: UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(UIRectCorner.TopRight))
    self.setMaskToView(self.bottomView, corners: UIRectCorner.BottomLeft.union(UIRectCorner.BottomRight))
}
```

Any thoughts as to how to fix 
1. the initial brief loading without the insets and
2. the final rendering of the initial load with the rounded corners on the right side not properly rendering?

This cell exists in a storyboard as a prototype, with the insets created via auto layout constraints.  (a constant setting the top and bottom view's distance from the top, bottom, right and left as appropriate).  Clearly these constraints work when the cell is reloaded, but not on the initial load for some reason that is escaping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently the answer was fairly simple.  The mask method was being called in layoutSubviews for the cell, the the views themselves did not yet have their bounds set.  So I subclassed the view into a new RoundedView class, and added a var for the corners and a modified mask method:

```
class RoundedView: UIView {

    var corners : UIRectCorner = []

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.setMaskForCorners(corners)
    }

    func setMaskForCorners(corners: UIRectCorner) {
        let rounded = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()

        mask.path = rounded.CGPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Then I changed the views to be that subclass and then call it like this:

```
    self.topView.corners = UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(UIRectCorner.TopRight)
    self.bottomView.corners = UIRectCorner.BottomLeft.union(UIRectCorner.BottomRight)
```